# Detecting the closing of a popup in Chrome, using Selenium

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome, selenium

I am writing a Selenium (server 2.31.0) test in PHP (5.3.15) that needs to test for a popup window closing.  The popup window is implemented using the [jQuery UI Dialog Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).  The popup itself contains some simple text (`HelloWorld`) that does not appear outside the popup.

Detecting the appearance of the popup is fine using `isTextPresent("HelloWorld");`.  I am then closing the window with `clickAt("//a[contains(@class, 'ui-dialog-titlebar-close')]");` (which I can see works) and then testing on the popup being closed with `!isTextPresent("HelloWorld");`.  I should add that I am doing appropriate things to make sure that the popup is being given time to open / close; there's a repeated pause & check cycle and I can also see the effect if I force the issue with an explicit sleep.

This works fine under Firefox (19.0.2) but is failing under Chrome (25.0.1364.172).  I.e. the window is being closed but I am not detecting this under Selenium.  I expect this is due to how Selenium does the `isTextPresent` check and/or the popup only being hidden as opposed to closed.

I am looking for a method for detecting the closing popup that works on Chrome.  Cross browser would be great but, for the moment, I would be able to run different tests on different browsers.

Comment: what about changing the method to `isVisible()` or `isDisplayed()`? My guess is that this popup will be still on the page, but hidden by javascript. So thats why isTextPresent can claim you that text is still there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An equivalent test (in terms of what the test is designed for, as opposed to the particular previous behaviour checked for) can be produced using `isVisible` on the popup (`isVisible("//a[contains(@class, \'ui-dialog-titlebar-close\')]");`) with a corresponding negative test after closing the popup.  This works under both Chrome (25.0.1364.172) and Firefox (19.0.2).

This is not doing the same check on the contents of the popup but, since the desired effect is to test for the popup's presence, it is sufficient.