# Ensure that a popup has been closed with Capybara/Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I am attempting to write a capybara spec which opens a popup, and then asserts that the popup has closed itself.

```
visit "/my_page"

click_button "Open My Popup"

within_window("MyPopup") do
  # test things on MyPopup
end

sleep 1 # long enough that window.close() has been called in the popup

# ensure that MyPopup is closed
```

Things I've tried so far...

Counting the window handles:
`page.driver.browser.window_handles.length`
This remains at 2 even after the popup is closed

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428831/detecting-the-closing-of-a-popup-in-chrome-using-selenium) suggests, check for the visibility of an element on the popup.  This doesn't seem to work.  Even though the popup has been closed, I can run assertions against the window as if it's still there, just as before:

```
within_window("MyPopup") do
  # test things on MyPopup
end
```

I'm ensured that window.close is firing from the popup (by adding some JS that modifies the popup's DOM after the window.close() and asserting on those changes).

I'm fairly stumped here; anyone out there know the secret sauce for asserting that the window actually closed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should wait for your page has no some specific css?

It may look like this:

```
def wait_for(timeout = 10)
  Timeout.timeout(timeout) do
    loop do
      break if yield
    end
  end
end

wait_for { page.first(:css, 'your.specific.css').nil? }
```